# DBPedia spotlight docker returning curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I'm trying to set a local dbpedia spotlight server with the docker image by calling:

```
sudo docker run -i -p 2222:80 dbpedia/spotlight-english spotlight.sh
```

the image runs and I get this when prompting `sudo docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
02282289ae64        dbpedia/spotlight-english   "/bin/sh"           About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:2222->80/tcp   sleepy_meninsky
```

but when I send a simple request as:

```
curl http://0.0.0.0:2222/rest/annotate?text=COOPER+Has+the+FBI+said+anything+about+a+reward+or+anything+%5C%3F+Because+there+was+that+there+was+a+reward+for+finding+her&confidence=0.5
```

or even one with a header set:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:2222/rest/annotate -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode "text=President Obama called Wednesday on Congress to extend a tax break for students included in last year's economic stimulus package, arguing that the policy provides more generous assistance" --data-urlencode "confidence=0.35"
```

I get the same error:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Can anyone help? Is this related to the need for sudo when I run docker?

Thank you for you time and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sandro for pointing out the need to run `spotlight.sh` when running the docker and also for the very useful `-d` flag, but what made the docker work and stop returning the curl error 56 was the `--restart unless-stopped` flag indicated as needed [here](https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/spotlight-docker)

Running this work for me:

```
sudo docker run -itd --restart unless-stopped -p 2222:80 dbpedia/spotlight-english spotlight.sh
```

Apparently, if that flag is off, the docker goes down. I've personally haven't observed that behavior on the ubuntu 18.04 I was running this through ssh, but when I've decided to install the docker locally on a mac machine, the image wouldn't stay running for longer than a minute. Adding this flag made the spotlight requests work on both environments.

Hope this helps someone else facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Checking Spotlight's Dockerfile at https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/spotlight-docker/blob/master/v1.0/english/Dockerfile, it hasn't an entry-point configured.

Please add spotlight.sh at the end of your docker command like:

> docker run -d -p 2222:80 dbpedia/spotlight-english spotlight.sh

Also, maybe you want to run it as a service using -d parameter instead of interactive mode -i.

All the best,

Comment: thanks for the -d flag, it does help :) but i still get the same errors when I add spotlight.sh at the end...